Problems with Lookup in SSIS, conversion of Excel uni-code now working
I have excel file, I want to make Lookup on it and save the result to new table in database.

I have already tried to change data types in Excel Source from Uni-code to String in Advanced Editor, so it was the same datatype as in reference table for Lookup. Now is is showing error "column cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode". Also I have set one column to float, because it is float in reference table, but when I try to map this columns in Lookup I still get this error:
.
Any suggestions?
Thank you for help.

salesdate field seems to me like a date or date time data type field, not a floating data type. Please provide the screenshot of Lookup transformation to make sure mapped columns have compatible data types.  how you did join them together? Unicode means 'nvarchar' and non-unicode means varchar.
